# KeyError Issue in value

Tags: python, python-3.x

could someone show me how to fix this please. not sure why i am getting this error.

Comment: Please post the full code. However, it's probably because you've used  ```FLAG1 = my_dict['FLAG']``` instead of ```FLAG1 = my_dict[FLAG]```

Comment: We can't be sure also as you didn't post all relevant parts of the code and not even the full error...

Comment: i have updated my post. please check

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
FLAG1 = my_dict['FLAG']
```

Is trying to access a nonexistent key. Before executing your program, ensure that in fact `my_dict` has a value associated to the key `'FLAG'`:

```
my_dict = { 'FLAG': 'some value' }
```

Comment: that is the issue, the key flag might not have a value set always and that might be causing the issue. wondering how to fix that

Comment: Nobody can tell, because you didn't post the code that creates `my_dict`.

Comment: i have updated my post with my full code. please check